# dplyr::group_by two columns of same variables, order doesn't matter

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to summarize a data frame according to values in two columns, except each column actually has the same variable in it and I don't care what the order is. Here is a sample data frame:

```
> df<-data.frame(val1=c(1,1,1,2,2), val2=c(1,2,2,1,1), val3=c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50))
> df
  val1 val2 val3
1    1    1   10
2    1    2   20
3    1    2   30
4    2    1   40
5    2    1   50
```

I am interested in summarizing over `val3` except I only care about the *unordered* combination of `val1` and `val2`. So for instance I want to treat

```
  val1 val2 val3
1    1    2   20
```

the same as

```
  val1 val2 val3
1    2    1   40
```

I can use dplyr to group by columns and summarize like this:

```
> df %>% group_by(val1, val2) %>% summarize(mean=mean(val3))
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: val1 [?]

   val1  val2  mean
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1    10
2     1     2    25
3     2     1    45
```

But I want this result to only contain two rows!

I've thought about creating a new variable that reflects the combination of `val1` and `val2` and then group by that, but can't figure out an easy way to this. `val1` and `val2` don't have to be numeric and likely won't always be consecutive integers.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15495795/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/28047997/

Answer (score 8):

We can do this with `pmin` and `pmax` to create the grouping variables

```
df %>%
    group_by(val_1 = pmin(val1, val2), val_2 = pmax(val1, val2)) %>% 
    summarise(val3 = mean(val3))
#   val_1 val_2  val3
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     1    10
#2     1     2    35
```

As @Gregor mentioned in the comments, the use of changed names was intentional (`val_1` vs. `val1` or `val_2` in place of `val2`) as the second statement `pmax` will evaluate the output from the 'val1' column if we had `val1= pmin(val1, val2)`